# Recommended MTA for Windows Server

Tags: email, email-server, smtp

I need an mail server running on my web server that will just route email through other email servers.  Exchange requires Active Directories which just complicates an otherwise simple setup.  What are your recommendations for a self contained windows mail server?

One thing I neglected to mention is that the MTA must be able to route email based on the from address.  So when someone sends mail from @microsoft.com it should route through mail.microsoft.com and when it sends mail from @apple.com it should route through mail.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the Windows SMTP server as suggested by Jason doesn't meet you needs you may be interested in [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/).

Comment: does this support relaying through another smtp server based on the from address?  e.g. send messages from @microsoft.com through mail.microsoft.com and messages from @apple.com through mail.apple.com...

Comment: @statichippo (cute name BTW), Sure looks like it. Have a read of this page from the hMailServer docs: http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_route

Comment: I saw this but it looks to me like this is used to route based on the recipient's domain name whereas I'm looking for the ability to route based on the sender's domain name.  Am I missing something you're picking up on?

Comment: @statichippo, it could be that I'm reading it wrong. However, it appears it's possible to route by recipient domain using rules. I'd suggest installing hMailServer on a test machine and having a play with it. I'm not in a position to test outbound routing.

Answer (score 1):

Windows server includes an smtp server. It's installed as a feature in 2008 or through add and remove programs in 2003

Comment: wow cool.  does this support relaying through other smtp servers based on the from address?